# Java generic design

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

I've `ErrorFactory` class which based on error code creates an instance of different type of Errors. Also I have `Output` class which might contains one of those error types.

Code below shows how I am trying to use it, but unfortunately getting error. Could you please help me figure out what is wrong there and suggest better design. Thanks for any help!

```
OutputLike output = new OutputLike();
ErrorFactory errorFactory = new ErrorFactory();
int errorCode = ((Long)error.get("error_code")).intValue();
output.setError(errorFactory.<Error>getError(errorCode, error));


Error:(97, 27) java: method setError in class com.electronsoftware.VKLiker.responseoutput.output.Output<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: com.electronsoftware.VKLiker.error.Error
  found: java.lang.Object
  reason: actual argument java.lang.Object cannot be converted to com.electronsoftware.VKLiker.error.Error by method invocation conversion
```

======

```
public class ErrorFactory <T extends Error> {
    public <T> T getError(int error_code, JSONObject errorBody){
        Error.ErrorType errorType = Error.ErrorType.values()[error_code];

        switch(errorType){
            case CAPTCHA_NEEDED:{
                return (T) Parser.parseCaptchaRequiredError(errorBody);
            }
            case USER_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED:{
                break;
            }
            case TOO_MANY_REQUESTS:{
                break;
            }
            case NOT_ENOUGH_PERMISSIONS:{
                break;
            }
            case UNKNOWN:{
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

====

```
public class OutputLike <E extends Error> extends Output <E> {
    ....
}

public abstract class Output <T extends Error> {

    private boolean isError;
    private T error;

    public boolean isError(){
        return this.isError;
    }
    public T getError(){
        return this.error;
    }
    public void setError(T error){
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

====

```
public static ErrorCaptchaRequired parseCaptchaRequiredError(JSONObject error){

    ErrorCaptchaRequired captchaError = null;
    ....
    captchaError = new ErrorCaptchaRequired(msg, captchaId, captchaUrl);
    return captchaError;
}
```

====

```
public class ErrorCaptchaRequired extends Error {
........
}
```

Comment: You should consider renaming these classes, `Error`s are serious problems that can result in an unstable JVM, such as an OutOfMemoryError. These should be `Exception`s, not `Error`s. Developers should never catch `Error`s unless there is a fantastically good reason for doing so.

Comment: The error is in the beginning of his post.

Comment: @Wrench So it does, I'd missed it

Comment: just cast agrument:
output.setError((Error)errorFactory.<Error>getError(errorCode, error));

Comment: Did you try defining `output` as the following instead? `OutputLike<Error> output = new OutputLike<Error>();` It looks like you don't know which type derived from `Error` you'll be stuffing into your `OutputLike` instance.

Comment: @MichałRowicki, I thought generics are made in order to avoid casts. :(

Comment: I don't think you need generics here. `getError` should just return `Error`. You should also heed the advice given by @JonK about `Error` vs. `Exception`.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

A) You are using a raw (untyped) `ErrorFactory`, which strips all generic info from the instance. Change to:

```
ErrorFactory<Error> errorFactory = new ErrorFactory<Error>();
```

B) Even if you fix A), you have typed `getError()` with `<T>` that is *hiding* the type `T` of the class.
Change

```
public <T> T getError(int error_code, JSONObject errorBody){
```

To

```
public T getError(int error_code, JSONObject errorBody){
```

Unless you really need to type the factory, I would make it untyped and simply return Error.

Also, naming any class the same as a java.lang class is a bad idea. Call it Problem or something.

Answer (score 2):

`ErrorFactory errorFactory = new ErrorFactory();` instantiates ErrorFactory with the default type, `Object`. You need to tell what type ErrorFactory should hold, when declaring it.

`ErrorFactory<CLASSNAME> errorFactory = new ...`

Comment: Thing is at the declaration of ErrorFactory I don't know exactly what type of error it is. Idea of error factory is to construct me required error object by passing just error_code. So given error_code it constructs me and return different type of errors.

Comment: so I don't see other solution than casting on base type

Comment: You have control over all classes? Might be time to refactor some.

Comment: This answer is on the right track for explaining the compilation error. In fact, using a raw `ErrorFactory` causes all methods to be erased as well. This causes `getError` to return raw `Object` despite the witness. (A witness is e.g. `<Error>` in `errorFactory.<Error>getError(errorCode, error)`.)

Comment: I do have access to all classes, do you have any suggestions how I can improve design by refactoring current model?

Comment: You have gotten good suggestions below so I will recommend them!

Answer (score 2):

So based on

> and suggest

if you want to consider another approach (tested and working), here is abstract solution. We have base

```
public class ValidationError{    
   public boolean isExpected() {
     return expected;
   }
}
```

to contain Error representation and attributes. Also

```
public class ScenarioError{
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
```

}

for test scenarios related errors, so we keep tracking them. Next is

```
public class ValidationErrorBuilder{
    public List<ValidationError> getValidationErrors(...){
    }
}
```

to construct found errors. And

```
public class ScenarioErrorsContainer{
   public String getErrorMessage() {
   }
}
```

to keep and get for processing already found errors.

Of course you'll have to add some required/needed interfaces (based on your case) in order to achieve better OO design.